# Sending Facebook apprequests without dialog

Tags: facebook

As it is possible to post on users wall without the request dialog using FB.api('Id/feed...), is it possible to send users an apprequests through the FB.api? and not FB.ui(apprequests...).

Thank you for your answer. I really need help on this I have been looking around for weeks...

Comment: dialog will appear always for security reason.

Comment: [this](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/) link says that you can use fb.ui() for single user

Comment: Thanks for the answer I knew about adding to in the FB.ui apprequests but it is still popuing the dialiog.
What about fb.api(Id/apprequest, post...)? In that way I can send an apprequest to my profile (that doesnt show in my feeds) but cant acces to my friends...

Comment: There's a more precise discussion about it at http://stackoverflow.com/q/8130271/235705

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7994122/facebook-app-invite-from-ruby-on-rails/8130271#8130271

Answer (score 3):

You can send apprequests from user to user and app to user.

The apprequests from user to user are initiated with the [Requests dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/dialogs/requests) box

App to User Requests can be used to re-engage a user in your app and can only be sent to users that have installed the app. For example, notifying a user that something has changed since their last visit, "10 of your friends are now online".

You can post a apprequest for a user by issuing an `HTTP POST` request to `/USER_ID/apprequests` with the [app's access_token.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/#applogin)

Answer (score 1):

It is currently not possible to send *apprequest*s without the dialog.

Comment: Well they intend for them to only occur in response to user actions, and you just can't trust app developers to not abuse that.