# Facebook app invite from Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api, koala

Is there any way to post a Facebook application invite from Ruby on Rails, e.g. by deploying Koala?

Looks to be impossible at the glance. Any workarounds other than simply posting to a wall?

Comment: Have you tried something like this? http://blog.otherscreen.com/2011/06/invite-facebook-friends-to-your-rails-app-omniauth-javascript/

Comment: if this was possible it would be a MAJOR spam generator... imagine if (with out user interaction) an application could just decide to send app invites to all of a users friends... spam-a-thon if u ask me...
TBH - I really hope this is not possible...

Comment: apologies for the pessimistic vibes :P

Comment: @Lix agreed indeed and as far as I've heard, this seems to be the case.

Comment: @mikeonrails Link not working

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Actually `mikeonrails` gave a correct link - the Requests dialog is *the* way to invite friends to your app and send them other types of requests. It *does* require user interaction though (just as the video shows), for requests sent to users who don't have the application installed.

And now for the details. There are 2 types of requests that you can send:

- user-generated requests: these can be sent to users who don't have the application installed (ie. application invite). They can *only* be sent using the Javascript SDK (or the iOS or Android SDKs but I don't think you're interested in those) and they *do* require user interaction. It will consist of a pop-up that will either display a selection (made by you) of his friends or a friend selector and a send button to send them your message.
- app-generated requests: these can *only* be sent to users who have the application installed, but can be sent without user interaction.

The code for user-generated requests is like this (using the Javascript SDK):

```
// this will show the pop-up dialog with a friend selector
// add a `to: 'friend_id1,friend_id2` to skip the friend selector
FB.ui({
    method: 'apprequests',
    message: 'My Great Request'
}, requestCallback);
```

For the app-generated requests you can use Koala like this:

```
user = Koala::Facebook::API.new(user_token)
user.put_object("user_with_app_installed_id", "apprequests", {:message => "Would you like to be friends?")
```

So, the conclusion is that you cannot invite a user's friends to your application without his approval, but you can make it really simple for him to do it (2 clicks).

If you'd like to read more:

- Requests Dialog: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/
- Social Channels: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/channels/#requests

Answer (score 4):

You can use Facebook Chat API to send private messages, here is an example in Ruby using xmpp4r_facebook gem:

```
sender_chat_id = "-#{sender_uid}@chat.facebook.com"
receiver_chat_id = "-#{receiver_uid}@chat.facebook.com"
message_body = "message body"
message_subject = "message subject"

jabber_message = Jabber::Message.new(receiver_chat_id, message_body)
jabber_message.subject = message_subject

client = Jabber::Client.new(Jabber::JID.new(sender_chat_id))
client.connect
client.auth_sasl(Jabber::SASL::XFacebookPlatform.new(client,
   ENV.fetch('FACEBOOK_APP_ID'), facebook_auth.token,
   ENV.fetch('FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET')), nil)
client.send(jabber_message)
client.close
```

---

UPDATE: Facebook chat API has been deprecated so it is not possible to use this solution anymore.